# Analog Blackfin Processor Silicon Revision issue

Tags: microprocessor, jtag, bootloader, processor

Recently we got a large batch of ADSP-BF5346s that say they are Silicon Rev 3 but internally read as Rev 2. Is there a way for me to determine the Silicon Revision number on the rest of the shipment without soldering all of them? I'm thinking a bootloader/JTAG but don't even know where I would find a bootloader for that.

Here's the code I might can use if I can find a way to load it

```
 /* silicon revisions 0.0    1.0    1.1   */

int silrev_list[] = {0x0, 0x100, 0x101};

int running_on = (*pREG_TAPC0_IDCODE & BITM_TAPC_IDCODE_REVID) >> 
BITP_TAPC_IDCODE_REVID; /* check the part */

int built_for = __SILICON_REVISION__; /* check what we built against */

int running_on_hex = silrev_list[running_on];



DEBUG_PRINT("Built for version %d.%d, running on version %d.%d\n", built_for>>8, built_for&0xff, running_on_hex>>8, running_on_hex&0xff);
```

Comment: This is definitely something you want to solve with the manufacturer, not with some strangers on the internet.

Comment: Did you buy these from Analog or from a reputable distributor ? If you did, then send them back and let them sort it out. If you ordered from EBay, this sounds like counterfeit parts. The rev might not be the only thing that's mismarked --- you might not have the speed grade you expected either.

Comment: I'd start with your vendor, to figure out if they know what they shipped you.  Digikey was very helpful to me when I bumped into  a problem with a silicon revision on an Analog Devices part.  I ended up on the phone with the warehouse to see what they could ship me.  Not quite your problem, but I got the feeling that Digikey had great tracking, and knows exactly what it ships.

Comment: The distributor may be a little less than credible, but I've always ordered from them in the past and never had an issue. This is why I'm trying to gather as much data as I can so that I don't send them in and find out only 5 of them were mislabeled. I'm beginning to think that they are counterfeit, which is why I would like to test the rest of them to be 100% sure.

Comment: What would you gain by testing all of them? Even if but 1 of your ordered chip isn't what you've ordered, it's not *your* job to sort it out.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my question. Is a bootload/JTAG the best method for verifying a Silicon Revision?

Comment: @JFisher - You would probably have to talk to the manufacturer to learn how to easily read out the silicon revision via the simplest method possible. It may even be possible to read it out via a direct JTAG command access to a register rather than having to load code into the part to read out like your software access works. You have to generally go to the manufacturer because often there are details regarding how the JTAG port on parts work that are kept secret or not disclosed unless you agree to a non-disclosure-agreement. On the other hand to get support there may be proof (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) of purchase requirements to show that you bought the parts from a legitimate supplier.

Comment: How are you going to test that they meet all specs? Over the entire operating temperature range? If these are test failures that went out the back door of the factory there could be a lot more subtle issues than the silicon rev that could lead to field failures in your product.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, if they are counterfeit, Analog might still be interested in getting them back, to see where their supply chain is leaking.

Comment: I agree that that Analog may be very interested. To find out the OP still needs to talk to them directly.

Comment: If rev 3 is more desirable then rev 2 they could be parts that have been ground and remarked by a dishonest middleman.   Or the asker could merely be confused in what to expect.  **Is a known rev 3 available for comparison?** The actual question asked is **unanswerable**, since "without soldering" requires some sort of socket or test fixture, and the **package type has not been stated.** . It might also be a good time to contact Analog's field applications engineer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - The part data sheet that I looked at showed BGA type packages. Not very easy to fixture up without a lot of effort.....but still possible with pogo pins.

Comment: As far as I can see "BF5346" is not even a valid part number (or a very obscure one) - typically there are only 3 numeric digits not 4.  In terms of the Blackfin family overall, I believe at least one member was available in a TQFP type package.

Comment: My apologies I didn't see the typo, but they are BF536s. From my understanding, Analog was contacted and they basically said "didn't buy them from us? not our problem..." Ended up writing a serial bootloader and going the JTAG method...20% success rate lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you purchased the parts from a reputable distributor and a sampling of the parts show the wrong chip stepping level then you should return the parts to the distributor for a refund or proper exchange.

Make sure that you read the vendor documentation completely so that you know 100% sure that you understand the chip version reporting system. Sometimes things may not be exactly as we think them to be.

Lastly if you purchased parts from a less than credible source, which may be done to save money, then you have what you have and your recourse is limited or nothing.

Comment: They all have the same lot code and date code, as well as displaying the "0.3" which the documentation describes as Silicon Revision 3. All I'm looking for is for a way to test them, and any processor I may have trouble with in the future, without having to solder.